# PHP create textfile on the fly download the file is that possible?

Tags: php, fwrite

Is it possible to create file.txt on the fly download it?

The file should be stored in `backup/process/_pro_links_date.txt`
but when I  download the file, it has no  `.txt`  extension and it was store on my folder.

#### HTML

```
<a href="?down=load">File</a>
```

#### PHP

```
if ( $_GET['down'] == 'load' ) {
$date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

$myFile = "backup/process/_pro_links_$date.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Title - Url - Live Date - Process Date \r";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM k_addlinks WHERE user_code = '".$_SESSION['user_code']."' ") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$dated = date("m/j/y g:i",strtotime( $row["date"] ));
    if($row["spider_date"] == 'never'){
        $sdate = $row["spider_date"];
    }else{
        $sdate = date("m/j/y g:i",strtotime( $row["spider_date"] ));
    }
    $stringData = $row['pro_name'] . $row['customDomain'] . $dated . $sdate . '\r';
}
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

$path = "backup/process/_pro_links_$date.txt";
$name = "_pro_links_$date.txt";
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);

readfile($path);
}
```

what is wrong with my codes?

Comment: Should work, unless I am missing a syntax problem. What is it doing instead of working?

Comment: _it download be no .txt file on file extension_ Does your operating system hide or remove file extensions?

Comment: what it was doing is just when i click download the filename is _pro_links_2012-09-09 only but no file extension it should be `_pro_links_2012-09-09.txt`

Comment: my OS is win7 then i check the `Show File Extension`

Comment: Does the file contain the data it is supposed to contain?

Comment: Im sorry Mr. Michael what do you mean sir?

Comment: I meant - was the file correctly created.  Anyway, I think I see the issue and added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the issue.  In your `Content-Disposition` header, you set the filename, but your filename contains spaces since you created it using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`. So you need to surround the filename with quotes in that header:

```
// $name contains a space, in the format _pro_links_Y-m-d H:i:s.txt
$name = "_pro_links_$date.txt";
// Surround the filename with quotes...
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name . '"');
```

Alternatively, remove the spaces from `$date` before using it in the filename:

```
$date = str_replace($date, " ", "_");
$name = "_pro_links_$date.txt";
```

Comment: @user1538668 It should be `\r\n` (Win/DOS) or just `\n` (Unix).  `\r` was used on old Apple OS.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving it to a file, just echo it after you send the headers.

Comment: I assume the file needs to be saved since it is a dated backup.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = "Hello world !!!";
$name = "name.txt";

$file = fopen($name,"wb");
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);

header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

print $content;
```

Comment: Your answer worked fine for me but needs editing from fwrite($file); to fwrite($file, $content); to work fine but I could not edit it as I am getting shown the message "suggested edit queue is full" Hope you can fix that when you can.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your comment Joseph !